# Kernel Debug Kit for Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

Where can I find a Kernel Debug Kit for Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion ? There is no link to 10.8 Kernel Debug Kit on the Apple site.

Answer (score 1):

Apple hasn't released it yet.Still waiting.

Edit:Its out (29/08)

Answer (score 0):

At https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action check

[√] Developer Tools

---

The *Apple Developer* 2012-11-01 release of the *Kernel Debug Kit* for OS X 10.8.2 build 12C60 was around six weeks later than the 2012-09-19 release of that build of the OS.

Assume that a waiting period is customary. Whether six weeks is longer than average, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

[Download Link](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Mac_OS_X/kernel_debug_kit_10.8.3_build_12d78/kernel_debug_kit_10.8.3_12d78.dmg)

Please make sure you have an Apple ID.